# Buttons for a timing game

Tags: arduino, button

I want to create a game with arcade style buttons using arduino. I know there are simple loops you can have to check for a button closing a circuit, but if buttons are checked sequentially in an arduino sketch would it not increase the chances of the first button in the loop winning by being the first circuit checked? Seems this chance increases if the sketch does more than just check for presses (control LED's, timer count down display, etc). What are ways to make sure the winner is truly the first to close their circuit rather than just the first circuit that is checked?

Comment: Check *all* buttons before deciding.

Comment: Research Input Interrupts

Comment: Connect both buttons to the same ATmega328 port (e.g. PORTB), then read the status of all 8 of the PORTB pins simultaneously by reading `PINB`, the PORTB Port Input Pins register. See ATmega328 datasheet section 13. I/O-Ports, section 13.4.4 PINB – The Port B Input Pins Address.

Answer (score 3):

Connect both buttons to the same ATmega328 port (e.g. PORTB), then read the status of all 8 of the PORTB pins simultaneously by reading PINB, the PORTB Port Input Pins register. See ATmega328 datasheet section 13. I/O-Ports, section 13.4.4 PINB – The Port B Input Pins Address. Assuming you're just getting started with programming, this is very similar to what you've been doing. The arduino's digitalRead function actually reads the selected Port Input Pins register, but then it only tells you about one of the eight pins. It's actually simpler to just read the PINB register directly, since you care about reading all 8 input pins simultaneously. Be sure to test for the case where both buttons are pressed simultaneously.

Interrupt handling is another approach, but since you indicate you're concerned about determining which button was pressed first, be careful to understand how interrupt priority works. In the event of a "tie" between two interrupt sources, the higher priority interrupt wins.

Answer (score 0):

If your button checking loop is quick, say >100Hz, the difference would be very difficult to detect.  But, if you want to do it properly, you should use an  [interrupt](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AttachInterrupt), which will call a method when any button is activated.  As the reference says, "Interrupts are useful for making things happen automatically in microcontroller programs, and can help solve timing problems."

You should make a variable that stores the ID of the winner (if there is one).  Once the interrupts are set up in the setup method, the main loop only has to check the winner variable.  Each of the various input buttons should route to a short method that checks that there is no winner and sets the winner variable if that is true.  The check that there is no winner is just to ensure that a second interrupt does not overwrite the real winner before the main loop reads the winner variable.